# how to add a hyperlink in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to reactjs my question is how to add a hyperlink which navigates to a different website in reactjs. I tried with this:

```
<Link to={"https://www.washfort.com"} target="_blank"><img src={logodark} height="100" alt="logo" /></Link>
```

but it navigates to localhost/3000/https://www.washfort.com

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You use `Link` for using react-router based navigation. But in this case you want user to navigate to a outside website, so here you just use `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="https://www.washfort.com" target="_blank"><img src={logodark} height="100" alt="logo" /></a>
```

Comment: thank you its working sorry for the dumb question.